# Installing Ubuntu on USB drive

Tags: system-installation, system

I want to install USB drive to use it as a PC wherever I go. I am seeing so many distributions along with architecture like Intel X86 or AMD x86. So which distribution should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AMD64 is for 64 bit processors regardless of the manufacturer (intel or AMD).

i386 is for 32 bit processors regardless of the manufacturer (intel or AMD).

i386 will run on a 64 bit processor and a 32 bit processor as well.

AMD64 will **only** run on a 64 bit system and will not run on x86 or 32 bit system.

I have found from experience that Xubuntu requires the least amount of resources.

I won't recommend Lubuntu until they come out with a QT variant.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you a 32bit version, to run on most of the machines, and Lubuntu for the same reason.

Comment: I will say that Lubuntu is superior in it's styling, especially the icon theme.